# C++ - Including one header file inside another header file to make global variables available for array declaration

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, global-variables, header-files

I have a class called `WorldState` where I would like to declare a multidimensional array called `covar_matrix[dim][dim]`. The global variable `dim` is of `int` type and is declared and defined inside `global.h` and `global.cpp`. Here are the contents of `WorldState.h` :

```
#ifndef WORLDSTATE_H
#define WORLDSTATE_H
#include "global.h"

class WorldState{

    public:
        WorldState(float [], float [][dim]);
        get_wstate();


    protected:

    private:
        float w_state[];
        float covar_matrix[][dim];

};

#endif // WORLDSTATE_H
```

Is it good practice to include one header (`global.h`) inside another (`WorldState.h`)?

It still throws the error:

```
||=== Build: Debug in slam (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
C:\Users\syamp\Documents\codeblocks\slam\WorldState.h|8|error: array bound is not an integer constant before ']' token|
C:\Users\syamp\Documents\codeblocks\slam\WorldState.h|16|error: array bound is not an integer constant before ']' token|
```

How can I declare this multidimensional array without passing any size through constructor?

**Edit:**
Contents of `global.h`:

```
#ifndef GLOBAL_H_INCLUDED
#define GLOBAL_H_INCLUDED

extern int marker_num;
extern constexpr int dim;

#endif // GLOBAL_H_INCLUDED
```

`global.cpp` :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cmath>
#include "WorldState.h"
#include "Robot.h"
#include "Sensor.h"
#include "Marker.h"
#include "global.h"

int marker_num = 10;
constexpr int dim = (2 * marker_num) + 3;
```

Comment: If you are looking into having dynamically sized lists, you may want to use a [linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list).

Comment: That's not the idea. I do know the dimensions.

Comment: Then hard code them. You also could also define them at the top.

Comment: I have the values in the global.cpp. I am trying to use those values. Pls see the edit.

Comment: Add the values in global.h

Comment: I was not sure if that was a good programming practice. But the link in my answer has convinced me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out that the easiest thing to do, which is also not a bad programming practice, is:

```
#ifndef GLOBAL_H_INCLUDED
#define GLOBAL_H_INCLUDED

static constexpr const int marker_num = 10;
static constexpr const int dim = (2 * marker_num) + 3;

using namespace std;

#endif // GLOBAL_H_INCLUDED
```

Here is a link to the answer I received:

[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42752144/c-why-do-i-have-to-include-cpp-file-along-with-instead-of-h-file-to-acces)

Answer (score 2):

Array dimensions aren't allowed to be arbitrary variables. You need to replace `dim` with a constant.

Comment: I tried declaring it as `const int`. Still didn't work.

Comment: `const` isn't good enough. It either needs to be `constexpr` (if you're using C++11 or later), or replaced with a #define.

Answer (score 1):

Array dimensions must be compile-time constants in C++.   A variable (even if declared `const`) isn't enough.   You need to either use `constexpr` (C++11 and later) or a literal value (like `100`) before C++11.    You can use a macro (like `#define DIM 100`) before C++11, if you want to give the dimension a name.

There is nothing stopping one header including another - the preprocessor simply does text substitution, so an `#include` directive literally is replaced (copy/paste) with the content of that header.   If that is done recursively (header A including header B which includes header A) it is necessary to use a mechanism like include guards to stop the recursion becoming infinite (which tends to make the preprocessor choke).

Comment: I understand that there is nothing stopping me from including one header in another. My question is if it is a good practice?

Comment: Also, I had to write one more line #include `"global.cpp"` , inside `WorldState.h` to get this done. Is that acceptable?

Answer (score 1):

You should declare your 'dim' variable like this in the header:

```
extern const int dimm;
```

Without the constexpr qualifier. Then in the global.cpp you can instantiate it like this:

```
constexpr const int dimm = 5;
```

Or like this:

```
const int dimm = 5;
```

Either will work, because the compiler is capable of realizing that the second is implicitly constexpr.

You would only use the constexpr qualifier if you are going to calculate the value in that same statement.
However, for your particular problem at hand I would recommend the use of an enum:

```
enum {
    dimm = 5
};
```

Enums are pure compile time constants, and take up no space at run time (if you don't assign any variables with their value), and work perfectly fine being in headers. That particular enum is an anonymous enum, meaning it has no name, and only one value, dimm.

Comment: Thank you for this reply. I had to do the same with `marker_num' to resolve the issue.

Comment: This solution requires me to include `global.cpp` inside `WorldState.h` instead of `global.h`. Is it acceptable or good practice? Any way to avoid it?

Comment: Manually copy/pasting declarations or definition into multiple compilation units is error prone.  Using a header file reduces such errors, so is better practice.  There is no difference if header files include each other in that regard.  Practically, header files normally have content (declarations, etc) that can be replicated without breaking the one-definition rule (ODR).  Content of .cpp files typically breaks ODR, so including one is bad practice. Even if copying the .cpp does not break ODR it can confuse programmers and result in errors, so is considered bad technique.

Answer (score 1):

I really hope you see this and haven't moved on with your life.

It is definitely a good practice to define your constant data in a header and use it throughout your application. The same thing goes for some static functions that you use throughout your application as well; you can create a `Utility.h` header and store your utility functions (printing something, math formulas that you use in general etc) and use that header everywhere. Including your own headers in your other headers is not different from including headers written by other people (such as `#include <iostream>`).

I personally don't like `constexpr` but I don't have a valid argument against it as well, just a preference. For me, `#define` is a more generic thing to use and pretty much means `static constexpr const`. When you use `#define`, you're basically telling the compiler to copy paste defined value into where its used. Example:

```
#define MAX_NUMBER 10
...

int cityLimit = MAX_NUMBER * 2;
```

Compiler swaps MAX_NUMBER with whatever you put next to it. It is literally copying and pasting it.

Here is the catch, don't use `using namespace std` in your code (especially in your global declaration or utility headers). `using namespace std` literally gets the entire namespace content and pastes it into wherever it sees it. It causes all sorts of problems, it totally namespace system and especially in larger code bases, it makes other developers hate you from time to time.

Most of the time, people use `using namespace std` to make writing `std::cout` and `std::endl` faster. For this purpose, you can change `using namespace std;` to

```
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
```

which does the same thing but only gets those functions from the namespace instead of everything in it.

Comment: No problem. Making codebases a better place one line of code at a time :)

Comment: Also, are you saying I can add both my `#include <iostream>` and `#include "WorldState.h"` inside `global.h` and then just type `#include "global.h"` everywhere?

Comment: Compilation-wise, it wouldn't cause any trouble. When you use ``#include "x.h"`, it literally takes the entire `x.h` file and pastes it on wherever you include it. I personally wouldn't use it if I'm not using `iostream` everywhere. However, it'll probably only make compilation time longer for compile time header guard checks. Other than that, I don't think it'd cause any problems.