# C++ - Why do I have to include .cpp file along with/ instead of .h file to acces the value of a global variable in the following case?

Tags: class, c++11, multidimensional-array, header, global-variables

I am trying to properly declare and define global variables in separate files and include them in a third file which deals with class declaration.

The three files are:

1) `global.h`

```
#ifndef GLOBAL_H_INCLUDED
#define GLOBAL_H_INCLUDED

extern const int marker_num;
extern const int dim;

using namespace std;

#endif // GLOBAL_H_INCLUDED
```

2) `global.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cmath>
#include "global.h"
#include "WorldState.h"
#include "Robot.h"
#include "Sensor.h"
#include "Marker.h"   

constexpr const int marker_num = 10;
constexpr const int dim = (2 * marker_num) + 3;
```

3) `WorldState.h`

```
#ifndef WORLDSTATE_H
#define WORLDSTATE_H
#include "global.h"
#include "global.cpp"

class WorldState{

    public:
        WorldState(float a[], float b[dim][dim]);
        get_wstate();

    protected:

    private:
        float w_state[];
        float covar_matrix[dim][dim];    
};

#endif // WORLDSTATE_H
```

I am using the global variable `dim` to declare and define a multidimensional array. I have declared `dim` inside `global.h` and defined it inside `global.cpp`. Now, I have a class called `WorldState` and inside its header, I am using `dim`. If I comment out `#include "global.cpp"`, it throws the following error:

```
C:\Users\syamp\Documents\codeblocks\slam\WorldState.h|10|error: array bound is not an integer constant before ']' token
```

My understanding is that including the `.h` file includes the corresponding `.cpp` as well, and that all declarations should be inside `.h` and all definitions should be inside `.cpp`. However, it doesn't seem to work in this case.

1) If I decide to include `global.cpp` file inside `WorldState.h`, isn't it bad programming practice? I am trying to write a good code not just a code that works.

2) An alternative is to define values of variable(s) `dim` (and `marker_num`) inside `global.h`. Is that good programming practice?

3) I believe there is something that I am missing. Kindly suggest the best method to resolve this issue. I am using `codeblocks` and `C++11`. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just place your constants definitions into global.h (i.e. move them from cpp to h-file). And don't use "extern". And NEVER include cpp-files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am using the global variable `dim` to declare and define a multidimensional array.

When declaring a fixed-length array at compile-time, the value(s) of its dimension(s) must be known to the **compiler**, but your separation prevents the value of `dim` from being known to the **compiler** at all, so `dim` cannot be used to specify fixed array dimensions.  Any code that uses `dim` will just compile into a reference to it, and then the **linker** will resolve the references after compilation is done. Just because `dim` is declared as `const` does not make it suitable as a compile-time constant.  To do that, you must define its value in its declaration, eg:

```
#ifndef GLOBAL_H_INCLUDED
#define GLOBAL_H_INCLUDED

static constexpr const int marker_num = 10;
static constexpr const int dim = (2 * marker_num);

using namespace std;

#endif // GLOBAL_H_INCLUDED
```

Otherwise, if you keep `dim`'s declaration and definition in separate files, you will have to dynamically allocate the array at run-time instead of statically at compile-time.

> I have declared `dim` inside `global.h` and defined it inside `global.cpp`.

That is fine for values you don't need to use until run-time.  That will not work for values you need to use at compile-time.

> My understanding is that including the `.h` file includes the corresponding `.cpp` as well

That is not even remotely true. The **project/makefile** brings in the `.cpp` file when invoking the compiler.  The `.h` file has nothing to do with that.

> that all declarations should be inside `.h` and all definitions should be inside `.cpp`.

Typically yes, but not always.

> If I decide to include `global.cpp` file inside `WorldState.h`, isn't it bad programming practice?

Yes.

> An alternative is to define values of variable(s) `dim` (and `marker_num`) inside `global.h`. Is that good programming practice?

Yes, if you want to use them where compile-time constants are expected.

Comment: Just to note: "static" is redundant, "const" implies local binding.

Comment: Thank You for the excellent, elaborate answer. I have one question related to your answer. I am running everything on Codeblocks. If need to run this from terminal, do I need to write a make file? Or can it identify `.cpp` files if they are all in the same folder?

Comment: @SyamprasadKR I don't how how codeblocks works. Typically, in most compilers, you use a makefile or project to organize things.

Comment: Okay. Thank you.@Remy Lebeau.

Comment: Point noted, Thank You. @KonstantinL